# random/empty characters while re-editing a json file

Tags: python, json, file-handling

I apologize for the vague definition of my problem in the title, but I really can't figure out what sort of problem I'm dealing with. So, here it goes.

I have python file:
*edit-json.py*

```
import os, json

def add_rooms(data):
    if(not os.path.exists('rooms.json')):
        with open('rooms.json', 'w'): pass

    with open('rooms.json', 'r+') as f:
        d = f.read()  # take existing data from file
        f.truncate(0)  # empty the json file
        if(d == ''): rooms = []  # check if data is empty i.e the file was just created
        else: rooms = json.loads(d)['rooms']
        rooms.append({'name': data['roomname'], 'active': 1})
        f.write(json.dumps({"rooms": rooms}))  # write new data(rooms list) to the json file

add_rooms({'roomname': 'friends'})'
```

This python script basically **creates a file rooms.json(if it doesn't exist), grabs the data(array) from the json file, empties the json file, then finally writes the new data into the file**. All this is done in the function add_rooms(), which is then called at the end of the script, pretty simple stuff.

So, here's the problem, I run the file once, nothing weird happens, i.e the file is created and the data inside it is:

```
{"rooms": [{"name": "friends"}]}
```

***But the weird stuff happens when the run the script again.***

**What I should see:**

```
{"rooms": [{"name": "friends"}, {"name": "friends"}]}
```

**What I see instead:**
[image: the json above with a bunch of 'weird' symbols/characters before it]

***I apologize I had to post the image because for some reason I couldn't copy the text I got.***

and I can't obviously run the script again(for the third time) because the json parser gives error due to those characters

I obtained this result in an online compiler. In my local windows system, I get extra whitespace instead of those extra symbols.

I can't figure out what causes it. Maybe I'm not doing file handling incorrectly? or is it due to the json module? or am I the only one getting this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you truncate the file, the file pointer is still at the end of the file. Use `f.seek(0)` to move back to the start of the file:

```
import os, json

def add_rooms(data):
    if(not os.path.exists('rooms.json')):
        with open('rooms.json', 'w'): pass

    with open('rooms.json', 'r+') as f:
        d = f.read()  # take existing data from file
        f.truncate(0)  # empty the json file
        f.seek(0)  #  <<<<<<<<< add this line
        if(d == ''): rooms = []  # check if data is empty i.e the file was just created
        else: rooms = json.loads(d)['rooms']
        rooms.append({'name': data['roomname'], 'active': 1})
        f.write(json.dumps({"rooms": rooms}))  # write new data(rooms list) to the json file

add_rooms({'roomname': 'friends'})
```

Comment: thanks @Mike67 I did that and it helped. I used f.tell() to see the position after truncating file, and during the second time I didn't see 0 as the position.